# Nib vs. View - How do they interact/overlap each other?

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to objective-c and it seems my question is so basic there's nothing concise on it around (I just end up more confused by reading things).

When you create a .xib file, you link it to a controller (usually, I think). At the same time, you can do things you can do in .xib by defining views in code. I thought I understood part of it when I realized most of the items you drag onto a .xib are view objects. I guessed from there that .xib were somehow just representing real code for views. Is that accurate? Or am I completely wrong? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Xib files do not represent real code for views, only the structure of the view's data. Each xib (or a storyboard) has enough information to do all of the following:

- Instantiate elements of the view
- Set properties of individual elements of the view
- Connect elements of the view in a hierarchy
- Connect "outlets" of objects in the Nib to properties or variables of views in your code.

However, there is no "real code" there, only the *metadata*. Cocoa has enough smarts to build and connect the objects, but the actual code is always in your .m files.

Answer (score 2):

A view controller manages a view which is made up of many subviews. While, every view can have only one superview at most. ( superview is nil for the top-most view). This is called the *view hierarchy*.

**The top level view in a hierarchy can be defined using pure code, or with Interface Builder, which produces a xib.**

Its useful also to explore the relationship of view controllers to each other. Within one application window, there can also be several view controllers, each managing their own top-level view. This is called view-controller containment. An example of this is a UINavigationController or tab-bar controller. . .in more complex apps it is common to set up your own root controller that manages this aspect of controller heirarchies. (Eg swipe to reveal a navigation controller, which is under the main content cotroller).

Answer (score 0):

A XIB describes arbitrary objects that conform to `NSCoding` but is usually used to layout a view hierarchy. So it'll be mostly `UIView`s, usually with a `UIViewController`.

However they're purely data. No code is generated. The system reads the XIBs and creates the objects purely as a data-reading exercise.

Objective-C has a fully reflective runtime — you can lookup classes by name as a string and can call methods on them the same way, without even knowing whether the method really exists in advance. Interface builders that secretly write code, such as Microsoft's in Visual C++, tend to do so because there's no way they could establish whatever you've described purely by parsing data.